# Using R to compute an integration

Tags: r, integration, numerical

The problem is below:

[image]

I am trying to compute the integration above by using R. Since I am new in R, I am not sure if my code is computing this integration correctly or not. I would appreciate if anyone can help me about this R code. My code is given below.

```
   x0<- c(1,3,0,0,0,3,1,6)
   x1<- c(2,3,6,0,0,5,6,6)
   n0<- 6
   n1<- 6
   N<-6
   k<-8

  f<- function(x0,x1,n0,n1,m,p){
  u<- (p+(1-p)*(m+1)*((x0[1]+x1[1])/(n0+m+1))*(sum(sapply(0:m,function(s)        {sum(sapply(0:m,function(t){((factorial(m)^2)*factorial(t+s)*factorial(x0[1]+s)/(factorial(2*m)*factorial(m+n0)*factorial(n1-t)))}))}))))
  for (j in 2:k)
  u<- u*(p+(1-p)*(m+1)*((x0[1]+x1[1])/(n0+m+1))*(sum(sapply(0:m, function(s)    {sum(sapply(0:m,function(t){((factorial(m)^2)*factorial(t+s)*factorial(x0[1]+s)/(factorial(2*m)*factorial(m+n0)*factorial(n1-t)))}))}))))
  return(u)} 

  int1<- function (p){sum(sapply(1:N,function(m)(1/N)*f(x0,x1,n0,n1,m,p)))}
  A<- integrate(Vectorize(int1),0,1)$val
  A
```

Comment: That looks like an impressive integration. My suggestion is to start with simpler integrations where you know the answer and then gradually add complexity.

Comment: I think you may also have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), where perhaps this extremely complex expression is not what you should be integrating in the first place, at least not without attempting some analytical simplification. At the least, you are going to run into possibly severe numerical accuracy issues with a naive implementation, especially given that you are multiplying and dividing factorials.

Comment: @lmo Thanks for your suggestion.Actually, I started with a simple integration where I knew the answer. And the code was working. Then I modified the code for this integration, it gives result but I think it is not correct result.

Comment: maybe it is a good idea to cross-post your question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/